# Java/Eclipse Dependency mapping / graphing tool - Where is a JAR being used in my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, dependencies

I have a JAR on the build path of a medium sized Java application and I would like to know where it's used. At the most basic level if someone could tell me how to 'Find References' for a Jar that would be great.

Whilst I'm looking at dependencies it would be great to find a tool that would map all of my package / external library usages and graph them. I used to have a free plug-in for eclipse that did just that but I haven't been able to rediscover it.

Thanks,

Gav

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Classpath Helper](http://classpathhelper.sourceforge.net/) or [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/).

Keep in mind that certain kinds of references might be missed (reflection, spring xml config files, etc.).

As a long term solution, using [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to manage your dependencies is a good idea.

Alternatively, if its just one jar file, remove it from your classpath and see what breaks ;)